# can't select element created using map() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, dom, element

I have displayed some element using Array.map function but now i cannot select any element that are created using Array.map function.when I select console log an element that is created using that map function it shows null

```js
const fetchData = function() {
  let display = products.map(function(product) {
    return `<div class="main relative lg:w-1/4 md:w-1/2 p-4 w-full">
<a class="block relative h-48 rounded overflow-hidden">
  <img
    alt="headphone"
    class="product--img object-cover object-center w-full h-full block"
    src=${product.img}
  />
</a>
<div class="mt-4 relative">
  <h3 class="category text-gray-500 text-xs tracking-widest title-font mb-1">
   ${product.category}
  </h3>
  <h2 class="name text-gray-900 title-font text-lg font-medium">
   ${product.name}
  </h2>
  <p class="price mt-1">${product.price}</p>
  <button
id="name"
    class="btn-add  absolute right-5 bottom-3 bg-orange-400 rounded text-sm px-2 py-2 text-white font-medium"
  >
    Add To Cart
  </button>
</div>
</div>`;
  });

  display = display.join("");
  mainSection.innerHTML = display;
};


window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fetchData);

let btnAdd = document.querySelector(".btn-add")

console.log(btnAdd)
```

Comment: Please add an example products object to the snippet I made you

Comment: `fetchData` runs when the DOM is ready to be used. Of course you can’t access elements before they exist.

Comment: is there any way to select them

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
let btnAdd = document.querySelector(".btn-add")

console.log(btnAdd)
```

inside `fetchData` at the very bottom, when the `.btn-add` is already created and appended to the DOM.

You try to access `.btn-add` when it hasn't exist yet, `DOMContentLoaded` event hasn't fired yet. `window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fetchData);` here you only add a listener, but not execute, so your HTML in `display` variable hasn't exist yet

Answer (score 0):

It happens that the fetchData method is called only after the DOM finishes loading, but the search for the element of your button is performed even before the loading of the DOM is finished (and in any case the element does not yet exist and the value is null)
If you search for the value "after" the loading of the DOM it will find the element

Comment: thanks, i have just found a solution myself. actually there is no need to add an event handler to the window to be able to display my contents. i can just call the function and it will also work the same.now i can select  all the elements